# Android closing child activity from parent activity

Tags: android, parent-child, activity-finish

I wanted to close child activity from parent activity. My flow is like: activity A is opened, inside Activity A I am opening activity B. But at same time my activity A is doing some background task. When I got result of my background task I wanted to close activity B from Activity A.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can start activity B by using `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)` then you can close activity B by calling  `finishActivity (int requestCode)`.

Comment: `startActivityForResult` is deprecated. What's the new way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

What you should do is start your activity with `startActivityForResult(yourIntent, childId);`

Then, when you want to kill your child activity, try `finishActivity(childId);`

Saw that [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397987/finish-child-activity-when-parent-activity-stops)

Comment: It's not, just quoting my source.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to finish() every activity once you leave it, Android will do that for you.
so you just restart Activity A to the top task .